# Mocking function from another crate

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking

I have created a new workspace with 2 crates: a web server and a Kafka library.

My web server is waiting for an HTTP POST request, extracting the field "hostname" from the JSON payload, and writing it to Kafka using my Kafka library.

Here is the main function:

```rust
async fn handler(Json(payload): Json<Host>) -> (StatusCode, Json<Host>) {
    let host = Host {
        hostname: payload.hostname,
    };
    info!("request from {}", host.hostname);
    match produce(Topic::Servers, host.hostname.as_str(), "server1").await {
        Ok(_) => (StatusCode::CREATED, Json(host)),
        Err(_) => (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Json(host)),
    }
}
```

Here is my Kafka produce function signature:

```rust
pub async fn produce(topic: Topic, message: &str, key: &str) -> Result<()> {
    // return Ok(()) if everything is fine
    // or and error if a problem is detected (kafka unavaible)
}
```

I want to test my handler function (and after that, the produce function). So I copied and adapted the  [axum example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/testing/src/main.rs#L86-L108)):

```rust
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn post_json_ok() {
        let app = app();

        let response = app
            .oneshot(
                Request::builder()
                    .method(http::Method::POST)
                    .uri("/")
                    .header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE, mime::APPLICATION_JSON.as_ref())
                    .body(Body::from(
                        serde_json::to_vec(&json!({"hostname": "example.com"})).unwrap(),
                    ))
                    .unwrap(),
            )
            .await
            .unwrap();

        assert_eq!(response.status(), StatusCode::CREATED);

        let body = hyper::body::to_bytes(response.into_body()).await.unwrap();
        let body: Value = serde_json::from_slice(&body).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(body, json!({ "hostname": "example.com" }));
    }
```

As you can guess, the test passes when the Kafka server is available and fails when it's down.

My idea was to mock the produce function and force the result to Ok(()) or an error, so I can write two test functions.

I found the crate [mockall](https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/) but I don't really understand how to use it to mock my function.

Thanks